# OutOfMemory error after rebuild in IBM RSA (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, ibm-rad

When I launch my **IBM RSA** workspace, dynamic memory grows up, and after a short time it crashes with an **OutOfMemory** error, with core dumps, etc.

I have discovered that the offender is a **large struts-config.xml file** (1.7mb). If I remove it from the project, the dynamic memory doesn't grows to much.

I run with this init parameters in my eclipse.ini:

*-vmargs -Xms40m -Xmx1512m -Xmnx64m*

Have somebody any clue to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's picking up the JVM options? Have you tried running `jconsole` to see?

Comment: Yes, I have monitorized it with jConsole. (thanks!)

Comment: I doubt it's the fact that the struts config file is 1.7mb in size that's the problem. It's probably the resulting framework and application code that's being loaded that's too large. You'll have to dig into the problem and update the question with more detail for people to be able to help.